# SSD memory combination

Tags: memory, ssd, storage

I have a question about SSD's.

I have read that there are SSD's that use a combination of RAM and flash memory so that RAM can receive a backup from flash memory when a power outage occurs.

I don't know if they meant two separate SSD's working together or a single SSD that has both of these memories. There wasn't much clarification about it and the only information I could find about hybrid SSD's was SSHD's.

So my question is: is there an SSD that has both RAM and flash memory inside of it?

Comment: Can you link the article that you have read. With the info you gave it is difficult to formulate a valid answer.

Comment: To be honest the information that ive read wasnt from an article but my comptia book that is unfortunatly not written in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search came up with the answer.

> Some SSDs, called NVDIMM or Hyper DIMM devices, use both DRAM and flash memory. When the power goes down, the SSD copies all the data from its DRAM to flash; when the power comes back up, the SSD copies all the data from its flash to its DRAM.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#Other)

The citation links to a [page](http://thessdguy.com/viking-why-wait-for-nonvolatile-dram/) where Viking Technology's NVDIMM SSDs are discussed.

> Viking’s NV-DIMMs are based on standard DDR3 DRAM, and have internal back-up flash that copies the contents of the DRAM in the event of a power failure.

Comment: @user3765147 Sure thing. You can choose to mark this as the selected answer if it solved your question.